# jQuery image rollover not working

Tags: jquery, html

Why isn't this working? I can't use CSS for this because the image will be changed if a child element is hovered over, as well as itself (unless I can?) Anyway, here is the code:

jQuery:

```
$("#prop-find-similar").hover(function(){
    $("#search-icon").src = "images/search-icon2.png";
    }, function(){
    $("#search-icon").src = "images/search-icon.png";
});
```

HTML:

```
<span id="prop-find-similar"><img id="search-icon" src="images/search-icon.png">Find Similar</span>
```

Comment: Just to confirm - whether you hover over IMG itself or the SPAN - IMG need to change SRC? IF so, it can be done in pure CSS

Comment: You could use a sprite to achieve this with css. Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/6r7W9/ also do a quick google on using sprite maps with css. This is a better solution than using jquery because it makes only 1 http request for the image instead of 1 request per image like you are doing here.

Comment: Yuriy, you're right, I could use pure CSS. I wasn't thinking. I could just put the image as a background for the <span> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#prop-find-similar").hover(function(){
    $("#search-icon").attr("src", "images/search-icon2.png");
    }, function(){
    $("#search-icon").attr("src", "images/search-icon.png");
});
```